# Query Array with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two JavaScript arrays. My first array looks like this:

```
teams: [
  { id: 1, name:'Flyers' },
  { id: 2, name:'Hawks' },
  { id: 3, name:'Bats' },
  { id: 4, name:'Ninjas' },
  { id: 5, name:'Seals' }
];

selected: ["1", "3", "4"];
```

How do I return an array of teams that have an ID in selected? I'm trying to do this with underscore.js Currently, I have:

```
  var selected = _.filter(teams, function (team) {
    return _.contains(selected, team.id);
  });
```

However, that's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `team.id` is a number, it will never appear in an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two step process for this. Using [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) inside a loop is a bad habit and you can skip it by precomputing a simple lookup table using [`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object):

```
var selected_has = _(selected).object(selected);
```

Since all the values in `selected` are truthy, we can say things like `if(select_has[id])` to see if `id` is in `selected`.

```
var matches = _(teams).filter(function(o) {
    return selected_has[o.id]
});
```

Of course, you pay a little bit for the type conversions but you gain expressiveness.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/b4XyU/